# Linker error on the new xcode (ios 8.2 simulator) in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I've recently updated xcode to the last version. So now my simulator have 8.2 ios version. My cocos2d-x projects are still working on devices (tested on ipad2 and iphone5s), but I can't compile them for simulator. I'm getting huge number of linker errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient", referenced from:
>
> -[CDAudioManager setMode:] in libcocos2d iOS.a(CDAudioManager.o)
>
> -[CDAudioManager applicationWillResignActive] in libcocos2d iOS.a(CDAudioManager.o)
>
> ...
>
> few hundred lines more
>
> ...
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed
>
> with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Showing first 200 notices
>
> only Showing first 200 errors only

Generally there are errors of all frameworks I use as well as cocos2d-x library itself. Before getting there most frameworks was highlighted red, but I fixed that making a symlink to:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

using this:

> sudo ln -s iPhoneOS.sdk iPhoneOS8.1.sdk

I'm of course using cocos2d-x 3.4.

edit:

After migrating to v. 3.5, setting valid architectures to: armv7, armv7s, i386, x86_64, setting build active architecture only to no (in both main and cocos2d_libs project) with various settings variations now I'm getting:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

And other's the same. Doesn't work on any simulator. I even downloaded 8.1 simulators and it doesn't work there too. This is some stupid linker error and I can't figure it out.

I've also noticed that fresh project builds fine. In my project I also have few objC classes (for other stuff like admob), which are using ARC. So I had to add "-fobjc-arc" in few places in build phases->compile sources. Problem is it's only simulator-related problem and appeared when I've updated ios sdk from 8.1 to 8.2.

Regards

Comment: i am facing same situation

Comment: I've found this problem in countless questions, but none of solutions are working.

Comment: is it compiling for device?

Comment: Yes it is. Until now I tried ipad 2, iphone 5s, iphone 6. Only simulator doesn't work.

Comment: seems like cocos2d could not be compiled for simulator..may be need to download some extra files

Comment: But it worked on 8.1. After updating sdk to 8.2 it suddenly stopped working. It's something on xcode side, not cocos2d-x.